# How to read time series climate data (i.e., precipitation) without extension in R?

Tags: r, time-series, raster, data-conversion

I have a file without any extension, which contain gridded daily temp_max(deg_c). The first two rows from the fourth column are indicates longitude and latitude respectively for each grid. Whereas First three column from 3rd row indicates year-month-day. And from the fourth column data are Tmax (Deg_c). For example please refer to following figure
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jykUs.png).
I want to make raster time series of daily gridded Tmax (Deg_c). So, can you please guide me how to convert these data in R?
Here is the link for the full data [Temp_Max](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1P2IN7k895j0o-OaJlkMADWLlhB1ul_j1?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some information about the data you used (such as the name of the dataset and the source). Then others with the same question are more likely to benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the data, create a single variable for the date, and transpose to other values to get a data.frame arranged as `lon, lat, z1, z2, ...`

```
d <- read.table("TMaxData")
dates <- paste(d[,1], d[,2], d[,3], sep="-")[-c(1:2)]
d <- t(d[, -c(1:3)])
colnames(d) = c("lon", "lat", dates)
```

Have a look

```
d[1:3, 1:5]
#       lon    lat 1951-1-1 1951-1-2 1951-1-3
# V4 88.875 27.125    14.35    13.25    11.07
# V5 89.125 26.875    20.76    19.39    17.88
# V6 89.125 27.125    12.63    11.53     9.47
```

Now we can coerce data.frame `d` to a SpatRaster, and set the time.

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(d, type="xyz", crs="+proj=longlat")
time(x) <- as.Date(dates)

x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 6, 13, 23376  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#extent      : 88.75, 92, 26.75, 28.25  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#names       : 1951-1-1, 1951-1-2, 1951-1-3, 1951-1-4, 1951-1-5, 1951-1-6, ... 
#min values  :    -2.01,    -2.51,    -4.36,    -3.42,    -1.70,    -2.30, ... 
#max values  :    21.55,    20.41,    18.82,    18.55,    21.70,    21.24, ... 
#time (days) : 1951-01-01 to 2014-12-31
```

Have a look

```
library(geodata)
btn <- geodata::gadm("BTN", level=1, path=".")
plot(x, 1)
lines(btn)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- use `fread` from `data.table` to quickly import this large dataset
- move latitude and longitude to the column names
- use `make_date` from `lubridate` to convert year, months and days into a single date column
- use `select` and `slice` from `dplyr` to remove useless rows and columns
- reshape your dataset to a longer format with `pivot_wider` (`dplyr`)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

dat <- data.table::fread("yourpath/TMaxData")

colnames(dat)[-c(1, 2, 3)] <- as.character(dat[1:2, -c(1, 2, 3)])

dat |> 
  mutate(date = make_date(V1, V2, V3)) |> 
  select(-c(V1, V2, V3)) |> 
  relocate(date) |> 
  slice(-c(1, 2)) |>
  as_tibble() |>
  pivot_longer(-date, names_to = "long_lat", values_to = "Tmax") |> 
  separate(long_lat, into = c("long", "lat"), sep = ", ") |> 
  mutate(long = gsub("c\\(", "", long) |> as.numeric(),
         lat = gsub("\\)", "", lat) |> as.numeric())
```

```r
#> # A tibble: 1,402,560 × 4
#>    date        long   lat  Tmax
#>    <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 1951-01-01  88.9  27.1 14.4 
#>  2 1951-01-01  89.1  26.9 20.8 
#>  3 1951-01-01  89.1  27.1 12.6 
#>  4 1951-01-01  89.1  27.4  3.37
#>  5 1951-01-01  89.1  27.6 -0.35
#>  6 1951-01-01  89.4  26.9 20.6 
#>  7 1951-01-01  89.4  27.1  9.55
#>  8 1951-01-01  89.4  27.4  7.23
#>  9 1951-01-01  89.4  27.6  1.93
#> 10 1951-01-01  89.4  27.9 -1.17
#> # … with 1,402,550 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I'm sure there are neater solutions - I'm not familiar with raster time series data. Hopefully, this will be helpful.